# Debian10 iptables-restore [legacy] just fails with simplest rule

Tags: debian, iptables, iptables-persistent

I'm trying to set up a simple firewall with docker and I wanted to use iptables-restore. I changed the iptables used to legacy (so shouldn't use nftables if I'm right).

The problem is that even a file as simple as :

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

leads to an error :

```
 iptables-restore rules1.v4 --test --verbose --noflush
Bad argument `COMMIT'
Error occurred at line: 3
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

The INPUT chain exists obviously :
`iptables -L INPUT`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I'm using Debian 10.

Comment: I just found the solution. It looks like iptables-legacy is somewhat broken on Debian 10 it seems. After switching to iptables-nft it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. It looks like iptables-legacy is somewhat broken on Debian 10 it seems. After switching to iptables-nft it works as it should.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what that switching entails? I'm currently trying to figure out the mechanism by which iptables-legacy tables get populated on Debian/Devuan, to perform the switch.